# Force index selection on combobox when item match C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have to force my combobox to change the selected index when user enters text and there is an item match. Right now i am getting the item match from my combobox like this:

```
 List<DataRowView> deliveryRoutes = ((ComboBox)sender).Items.Cast<DataRowView>().ToList();
if (deliveryRoutes.Where(q => q.Row[0].ToString().ToLower().Equals(((ComboBox)sender).Text.ToLower())).Count() != 0)
{

}
```

This code checks if the user input is a match with the combobox datasource. in my if statement i want to set the selected index of my combobox to be the matched text. Like so:

```
DeliveryRouteID.SelectedIndex = matchedTextIndex
```

I have tried getting the index from this without any luck:

```
deliveryRoutes.Where(q => q.Row[0].ToString().ToLower().Equals(((ComboBox)sender).Text.ToLower())).FirstOrDefault().Row[0]
```

How would i get the index and set it to be the selected index ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [ComboBox.FindStringExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstringexact.aspx) or [ComboBox.FindString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstring.aspx)

```
cmb.SelectedIndex = cmb.FindStringExact(item);
```